# What does it call for the menu show as slide up?

Tags: react-native

[React Native]
Can anyone help to elaborate what should that kind of menu called? When onclick, it slided up. Please also introduce what are other menu's available in react native? (Must work for both android and iOS)

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcjtB.png)

Comment: I'd tried context menu, reverse menu, sub menu with no luck. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is [share](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/share) dialog and you can easily implement it in React Native

Try this code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Share, Button} from 'react-native';

class ShareExample extends Component {
  onShare = async () => {
    try {
      const result = await Share.share({
        message:
          'React Native | A framework for building native apps using React',
      });

      if (result.action === Share.sharedAction) {
        if (result.activityType) {
          // shared with activity type of result.activityType
        } else {
          // shared
        }
      } else if (result.action === Share.dismissedAction) {
        // dismissed
      }
    } catch (error) {
      alert(error.message);
    }
  };

  render() {
    return <Button onPress={this.onShare} title="Share" />;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

React Native Modal

> 1-
> [react-native-modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal)
>
> 2-
> [react-native-modalbox](https://github.com/maxs15/react-native-modalbox)